# how to access the next argument of command line parameters in bash?

Tags: bash

Say I have the following:

```
for i in $@; do
    echo ${i+1}
done
```

and I run this on shell `$ test.sh 3 5 8 4`, it outputs `1 1 1 1`
why wouldn't ${i+1} work? I am trying to access the next argument for a list of command line arguments.

Comment: What do you mean *next argument*? Do you mean if gave 3, then you want 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each character in shell may have an special meaning.

The code `${i+1}` does not mean "add 1 to i".
To find what it means, execute this command:

```
LESS=+/'\{parameter\:\+word\}' man bash
```

And read:

> `${parameter:+word}`
>   Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

And a little way above:

> Omitting  the  colon  results  in  a  test only for a parameter that is unset.

As `$i` has a value set by the loop `for i in $@;` the "Alternate Value" is substituted and `1` is printed.

If you want to add 1 to the value of the arguments, do this:

```
for    i
do     echo "$((i+1))"
done
```

There is no need for the `in "$@"` (and get used to quoting all expansions).

```
$ ./test.sh 3 5 8 4
4
6
9
5
```

#### Next argument.

But that is not "the next argument" either. The core issue is with your loop, you are using the value of arguments in a loop, not an index to the arguments. You need to loop over an index `i` of the arguments, not the value `i` of each argument. Something like:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

That will print an index, as this shows:

```
$ ./test.sh 3 5 8 4
1
2
3
4
```

#### Indirection

How do we access the argument at position `$i`?: With indirection:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```

See the simple `!` added ?

Now it runs like this:

```
$  ./test.sh  3 5 8 4
3
5
8
4
```

#### Final solution.

And to print both the present argument and the next, use this:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    j=$((i+1))
    echo "${!i} ${!j}"
done
```

No, there is no simpler way than to calculate the value in the variable `$j`.

---

```
$ ./test.sh 3 5 8 4
3 5
5 8
8 4
4
```

That works for text also:

```
$ ./test.sh sa jwe yqs ldfgt
sa jwe
jwe yqs
yqs ldfgt
ldfgt
```

Comment: very well explained. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful. You taught me.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code i is the value, not the index.

You'll need the exclamation mark for using a variable value as variable.

I didn't get the (i+1) to work without defining another variable. Maybe someone can give a hint to optimize that.

```
check () {
  for i in $(seq $#); do
    let j=i+1
    echo "$i: i=${!i} i+1=${!j}"
  done
}

check a b c

1: i=a i+1=b
2: i=b i+1=c
3: i=c i+1=
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that, `${i+1}` is an parameter expansion pattern, which means if parameter `i` is Not unset or null, it will be substituted by the expansion of `1`, which of course just results in `1`. Hence you are getting all 1's in the output.

You need to use an arithmetic operator, not parameter expansion.

**For example:**

```
% check () { for i in "$@"; do echo $((i+1)); done ;} 

% check 2 4 5 6
3
5
6
7
```

Comment: hi, I meant to ask how to access the next/previous argument using just `i`

Answer (score 0):

I find myself using shift for the same purpose. Here's a small example taken from [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script can clean up files that were last accessed over 365 days ago.

USAGE="Usage: $0 dir1 dir2 dir3 ... dirN"

if [ "$#" == "0" ]; then
    echo "$USAGE"
    exit 1
fi

while (( "$#" )); do

if [[ $(ls "$1") == "" ]]; then 
    echo "Empty directory, nothing to be done."
  else 
    find "$1" -type f -a -atime +365 -exec rm -i {} \;
fi

shift
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [user79743's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261186/538009) answer above:

Suppose we want to have a argument that takes a value like `--mode delete` or `--mode list`.

When `${!i} == "--mode"`, we want to read the value for the *following* index (`j` or `i+1`) and retain it for later. Consider that on the next loop iteration that we will end up inspecting `i+1` a second time (was `j` on previous loop, is `i` on the current loop).

I found that `i` is mutable, so we can increment it by 1 meaning that the next loop iteration will be `i+2`, so to speak.

I did want to say that, generally speaking, it is unwise to mutate a value while iterating it. This approach did work for me. I'm sure there are probably several (better) ways to do this.

### Without incrementing `i`. Some indexes are inspected more than once.

```
# $ ./test.sh --mode delete 3 5 8 4
# [1]: --mode [2]: delete
# [2]: delete # <-- index [2] is inspected twice
# [3]: 3
# [4]: 5
# [5]: 8
# [6]: 4
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
  if [[ ${!i} == "--mode" ]]; then
    j=$((i+1))
    MODE=${!j} # retain for later
    echo "[$i]: ${!i} [$j]: ${!j}"
  else
    echo "[$i]: ${!i}"
  fi
done
```

### With incrementing `i`. Each index is only inspected once.

```
# $ ./test.sh --mode delete 3 5 8 4
# [1]: --mode [2]: delete
# [3]: 3
# [4]: 5
# [5]: 8
# [6]: 4
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
  if [[ ${!i} == "--mode" ]]; then
    j=$((i+1))
    MODE=${!j} # retain for later
    echo "[$i]: ${!i} [$j]: ${!j}"
    i=$i+1 # <-- incrementing the index
  else
    echo "[$i]: ${!i}"
  fi
done
```